Confusion about Laravel policy arguments
I'm trying to implement Policies in my Laravel application but am having some trouble with the parameters passed.
I have a very basic Policy named EmployeePolicy
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Employee;
use App\Models\Permission;

class EmployeePolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given employee can view a permission.
     *
     * @param Employee $Employee
     * @param Permission $Permission
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function view(Employee $Employee, Permission $Permission): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}

This policy is called from a controller function view
public function view (Request $request, Employee $Employee, Permission $Permission) { ... }

from a route which looks like
Route::get('/actions/{employee}/{permission}' [\App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationPermissions::class, 'view'])

In my view function, if I call my Policy with $request->user()->can('view', $Permission), it will always return false (even if I try to dd() in the policy, it will never be called). The policy function will never be called as I assume the function signature is different.
However, if I call my policy with $request->user()->can('view', [Auth::User(), $Permission]) then my policy will return the error
App\\Policies\\EmployeePolicy::view(): Argument #2 ($Permission) must be of type App\\Models\\Permission, App\\Models\\Employee given

I do somewhat understand why it's throwing this error, but I do not understand the proper way to be passing my Permission model to my Employee policy. The documentation has not helped me. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

What Laravel version are you using?

When you use $request->user()->can('view', $Permission), it will try to find a policy assigned to the Permission model (eg. App\Policies\PermissionPolicy).
To make things simple, you should create a PermissionPolicy class and move the view method to that class.
